# bash script for creating and then downloading the links

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting

Hellooo.

So I'm wanting to make a script for my girlfriend that uses an external file to append words to a URL, then download the links and iterate.
 The awkward thing is she doesn't want to tell me too much (I suspect the result of using the script will be for my benefit :P), so I'm not certain about the function, kind of guessing.
The aim is to get the script to contain a base URL. The script will iterate through an external file that contains a list of word and then append each word to the link. Then the script will then open that link. Then iterate through, append, open etc.

Can someone help me out a bit with this? I'm a bit new to scripting.

Should I set up an external file to hold the base url and then refer to that as well?

I'm thinking somthing along the lines of:

```
url=$(grep * url.txt)
for i in $(cat file.txt);
do 
>> $url
wget $url
done
```

What and how much do I need to change and add?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have posted an answer but i think it will hardly help you to impress your girlfriend. Well, if it does, then voila ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a file named `source` which has below content in it :

```
which-2.16.tar.gz
which-2.17.tar.gz
which-2.21.tar.gz
```

I wrote a script named `downloader` with the below content :

```
#!/bin/bash
url="http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/which" #source url
while read line
do
wget "$url/$line" #download url = source url + file name from the file
done <source #feeding filenames from the source file.
```

On running `downloader` will download the files mentioned in `source` file from the ftp site mentioned in `url`. Voila !!

I guess you could employ a similar concept.